# Read data from database and save in entities, BUT in which datatype?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have 3 tables:

```
1   User (USERID, Name, Age, Phone Number, FK_VennerID)
2:  Friends (VENNERID, name, age, gender, FK_LokationID)
3:  Location (LOKATIONID, Zip code, city name)
```

Based on the 3 tables, i have maked the Entity Model like this​ in my asp.net program:

```
public class User
  {
      public int USERID {get; set;}
      public string Name {get; set;}
      public int Age {get; set;}
      public int Phone Number {get; set;}

      public virtual ICollection <Venner> Friends {get; set;}
  }

  public class Friends
  {
      public int VENNERID {get; set;}
      public string Name {get; set;}
      public int Age {get; set;}
      public int LokationID {get; set;}

      public virtual User User {get; set;}
      public virtual Location Location {get; set;}
  }

  public class Location
  {
      public int LokationID {get; set;}
      public int Zip {get; set;}
      public string Town {get; set;}

      public virtual ICollection <Venner> Friends {get; set;}
  }
```

Let us now assume that I have in my database defined a sql stored procedure, which takes 1 input parameter and gives me the following data from 3 tables:

```
User.name, 
Friends.name, 
Friends.age, 
lokation.Zip, 
Lokation.Town
```

Soo How do I save so data from sql SPOC in Entities objects.

If data were only of ONE type I could have done this:

```
User user = new User ();

user.navne = datafrabasen;
user.xx = datafrabasen;
```

But now we have mixed data from the base, which has both user class Friend class and class location to do ..

I want to save data from the database into a list ... which can be called from font layer!

```
Return to List <Type> xxxx ();
```

Answer (score 1):

Create new type which holds all returning columns of stored procedure and then
use `List <NewType>()`
after that you can split the list to 3 new list that each list hast its own class data

Comment: Is this normal way do do it ?

Why shold i split list into 3 types after... It will make performance bad ..?